# center form inputs responsively

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get these input fields to responsively be centered but I'm having a bit of trouble. Can someone let me know where I might be going wrong? I tried creating a parent div and then the container element but can't the "margin: 0" doesn't seem to be working.

[Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blanah/kkh7f76h/)

HTML

```
    <div id="settings-info">
        <div class="settings-info-container">
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="userUpdateForm">
            <input type="text" id="userFnameValue" class="userInfoValues" placeholder="First Name"
                 value="{{ userSettings[0]['fName'] }}"/> <br>

            <input type="text" id="userLnameValue" class="userInfoValues" placeholder="Last Name"
                 value="{{ userSettings[0]['lName'] }}"/> <br>

            <input type="text" id="userLocalValue" class="userInfoValues" placeholder="Location"
                   value="{{ userSettings[0]['userLocation'] }}"/> <br>

            <input type="text" id="userNameValue" class="userInfoValues" placeholder="UserName"
            value="{{ userSettings[0]['userName'] }}"/><br>

            <input type="text" id="userGenderValue" class="userInfoValues" placeholder="Gender"
            value="{{ userSettings[0]['userGender'] }}"/> <br>

            <input type="text" id="userEmailValue" class="userInfoValues" placeholder="Email"
                   value="{{ userSettings[0]['emailAddress'] }}"/><br>

            <div id="info-pref-sub-btn">
              <span id="info-pref-sub-text">Update Info</span>
           </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#settings-info{
    position: absolute;
    top: 395px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
    /*background-color: red;*/
    width: 100%;
}

.settings-info-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
    /*background: green;*/
}

.userInfoValues{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 120%;
    text-align: center;
    left: 9%;
    width: 82%;
    /*width: 250px;*/
    height: 38px;
    margin: 12px auto 18px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background: #000;
    color: white;
}

/*same as our access and details submit button...may want to put in a class*/
#info-pref-sub-btn {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 145%;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #0070a3;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
#info-pref-sub-text{
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
}
```

Comment: What's not centered? the fiddle looks good

Comment: does it? I'm running it in Chrome and it seems fine in chrome but on an iphone5 and 6 it seems off and veers towards the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this look? I added `left: 0` to make sure the content is on the left most side

```
#settings-info{
    position: absolute;
    top: 395px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
    /*background-color: red;*/
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Update

Sorry I forgot one update I made

https://jsfiddle.net/kkh7f76h/4/

I removed left from `.userInfoValues` and used text-align center on `#settings-info`

Comment: hmmm...still off centered on the 5 and 6. It is weird though cause everything looks fine in the emulator. I may have to delve into this more. Thanks though ;)

Comment: @stingMantis sorry forgot an update, check the new fiddle

Comment: @stingMantis please mark correct if this is the answer you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

The CSS3 has changed a bit more. With the help of flexbox, we can do it easily.

```
#settings-info{
position: absolute;
top: 395px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
width: 100%;
}

.settings-info-container{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
}

.settings-info-container form {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.userInfoValues{
    font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background: #000;
    color: white;
}
```

I actually changed nothing but the property of the container form only. Please check it. It is far better than the traditional methods and responsive at all times. The one and the only issue is the browser compatibility of the flexbox.

You can check the code at [Codepen](https://codepen.io/abinthaha/pen/XgZxJQ)